# String Compress with while and for loop

Tags: python-3.x

I am doing a string compress feature with while and for loop. The idea is: 
1. Use the 1st character to loop through the string, and then stop when the next char is not the same 
2. slide the old string by remove the first same characters 
3. redo the loop until the string len = 0.

Somehow my initial code didnt work -> I use a helper ( adding 2 "$$" characters to end of initial string, and loop until last 2 $$.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem without  using the helper! 
thank you very much.

here is my code:

```
text = 'aaxxxxxxxbccccaaxxxaa'
text =text+"$$"  # this is the helper, I would like the do the task without 
using helper
count=0
result=''
while len(text)>2: 
    for x in range(0,len(text)):
        if text[x]==text[0]:
            #print( text[x])
            count+=1
        else:

            print(text[0]+str(count))
            result = result+text[0]+str(count)
            print(result)
            text =text[count:]
            count=0
            break
```

P.s If I don't use helper, I get Out of string range.

Comment: The code posted won't yield an `IndexError`, with or without the `text=text+"$$"` line. Please edit the question to include the code that generates the error and the full text of the error.

Answer (score 0):

this code below will print: **a2x7b1c4a2x3a2**

```
text = 'aaxxxxxxxbccccaaxxxaa'
text =text+"$$"  # this is the helper, I would like the do the task withou using 
                                                                           helper
count=0
result=''
while len(text)>2: 
    for x in range(0,len(text)):
        if text[x]==text[0]:
            #print( text[x])
            count+=1
        else:

            #print(text[0]+str(count))
            result = result+text[0]+str(count)
            #print(result)
            text =text[count:]
            count=0
            break
print(result)
```

I want to remove helper, and get the same **a2x7b1c4a2x3a2** with the 2nd code below, but Jupiter notebook will die (I guess infinite loop happen)

```
text = 'aaxxxxxxxbccccaaxxxaa'
count=0
result=''
while len(text)>0: 
    for x in range(0,len(text)):
        if text[x]==text[0]:
            #print( text[x])
            count+=1
        else:

            #print(text[0]+str(count))
            result = result+text[0]+str(count)
            #print(result)
            text =text[count:]
            count=0
            break
print(result)
```